# Sticky sidebar flickers during scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created this sidebar which sticks when the bottom of the div reaches it's bottom. However, it seems to flicker when I scroll. Could you help what am I doing wrong?

HTML

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="stickymain">
    <div class="side" id="stickyside">
      <p>
        This is the best we could do and there's nothing more one could expect from here to carry from onwards. I think there's nothing better too.
      </p>
      <p>
        This is the best we could do and there's nothing more one could expect from here to carry from onwards. I think there's nothing better too. This is the best we could do and there's nothing more one could expect from here to carry from onwards. I think there's nothing better too. This is the best we could do and there's nothing more one could expect from here to carry from onwards. I think there's nothing better too.11
      </p>
     </div>
    <div class="main"></div>
    <div class="main"></div>
    <div class="main"></div>
    <div class="main"></div>
    <div class="main"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
<script>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}
#header {
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    background: red;
}
#content {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 -110px 0 0;
}
.side {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    /* min-height: 500px; */
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
}
.main {
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 110px 10px 0;
    background: lightgray;
}
#footer {
    clear: both;
    height: 100px;
    background: orange;
}
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery.fn.stickyTopBottom = function(){
                    var options = {
                        container: jQuery('#stickymain'),
                        top_offset: 0,
                        bottom_offset: 0
                    };
                    console.log(options);
                    let jQueryel = jQuery(this)

                    let container_top = options.container.offset().top
                    let element_top = jQueryel.offset().top

                    let viewport_height = jQuery(window).height()
                    jQuery(window).on('resize', function(){
                        viewport_height = jQuery(window).height()
                    });



                    let current_translate = 0
                    let last_viewport_top = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop
                    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
                        var viewport_top = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop
                        let viewport_bottom = viewport_top + viewport_height
                        let effective_viewport_top = viewport_top + options.top_offset
                        let effective_viewport_bottom = viewport_bottom - options.bottom_offset


                        let element_height = jQueryel.height()

                        let is_scrolling_up = viewport_top < last_viewport_top
                        let element_fits_in_viewport = element_height < viewport_height

                        let new_translation = null
                        if (is_scrolling_up){
                            if (effective_viewport_top < container_top)
                                new_translation = 0
                            else if (effective_viewport_top < element_top + current_translate)
                                new_translation = effective_viewport_top - element_top
                        }else if (element_fits_in_viewport){
                            if (effective_viewport_top > element_top + current_translate)
                                new_translation = effective_viewport_top - element_top

                        }else {
                            let container_bottom = container_top + options.container.height()
                            if (effective_viewport_bottom > container_bottom)
                                new_translation = container_bottom - (element_top + element_height)
                            else if (effective_viewport_bottom > element_top + element_height + current_translate)
                                new_translation = effective_viewport_bottom - (element_top + element_height)
                        }
                        if (new_translation != null){
                            current_translate = new_translation;
                            console.log('i am here at css');

                            jQueryel.css('transform', ('translate(0, '+current_translate+'px)'));
                        }
                        last_viewport_top = viewport_top
                    });
                }
                jQuery('#stickyside').stickyTopBottom();
            });
```

Except for the flickering issue when I scroll, everything else is working just the way I want. I'm on Mac using Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

[**CodePen Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XpYaNK)

Comment: Sorry i don't understand very well the expected result. The sidebar should be fixed, or became fixed when reached its top ?

Comment: No, when it reaches the bottom of the sidebar, it should stick. As shown exactly. However, the sidebar instead of sticking, it "flickers" when I scroll further down.

Comment: Try scrolling and you will notice the flickering effect which I don't want.

Comment: OK. I see the flickering, only in IE. In Chrome it works well. In Firefox there's not flickering but the footer div overlaps the sidebar

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using only javascript to do all the work, you can use css properties to help you.

You can just change the position property of your side bar when reaching a certain point of the viewport:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var sTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    var footerTop = $('#footer').offset().top;
    var sideHeight = $('.side').height();
    var headerHeight = $('#header').height();

    if(sTop > headerHeight + (sideHeight/2)) {
      $('.side').css({
        position:'fixed',
        bottom:'10px'
      });
    } else {
      $('.side').css({
        position:'absolute',
        bottom:'inherit'
      });
    }
});
```

See this [PEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wgXbZg)

I hope this one it's ok! :)

Comment: Your solution sticks only at the top which I don't want. What I want is the complete opposite: How do I make the sidebar stop when it reaches the bottom?! Thanks though.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's why I wrote "..I've done the function only for top part of the side bar.." :D I will give the complete solution in a while.

Comment: Thanks. That would be awesome :)

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough and couldn't explain properly. I don't want the sidebar to stick at the top at any point of time. I want the sidebar to stick when it reaches the bottom. Exactly like the sidebar at medium_dot_com.